# Drag and drop multiple items between two nested trees in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

**Does anyone know any react component library which provides the feature to drag and drop multiple items between two trees in a web-app?**

Comment: what's the context? you mean drag and drop a picture from your desktop onto the website for a file upload, or something like that?

Comment: It's specific to a web app